# Unable to get Text on screen using SDL_TTF?

Tags: visual-c++, sdl, truetype, game-development, sdl-2

I have currently been trying to figure out displaying text on the screen. The problem however is that I can't seem to get anything on screen. I have looked at many tutorials on the matter and I believe that my problem lies in the actual "blitting" to the screen. In most tutorials I have looked at they have used the "BlitSurface" method. Although since I am using SDL2.0.3 I don't think that really works. I am trying to do some bare-bones class of getting the image on the screen but it just stays blank. Any advice and/or solutions?

Game.ccp

```
   #include "Game.h"
using namespace std;

bool Game::onInit(char*title, int width, int height, int fullscreen)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, fullscreen);
    if (gWindow == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create window \n";
    }
    else
        cout << "Created window! \n";
    gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (gRenderer == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to create renderer! \n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Created renderer! \n";
        gRunning = true;
    }
    TTF_Init();

    //Calling the Text.h function init.
    text.init(0, 0, 24, "bin/font/Pixel.ttf", "HELLO", gRenderer, { 255, 255, 255 });



    return gRunning;

}


void Game::onHandleEvents() 
{
    SDL_Event Event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&Event) != 0)
    {
        if (Event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            gRunning = false;
        }

        switch (Event.key.keysym.sym)
        {
        case SDLK_ESCAPE:
        {
            gRunning = false;
        }

        }
    }
}


void Game::onUpdate()
{

}

void Game::onRender()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

    //Calling Text.h draw function.
    text.draw(gRenderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
}

void Game::onClean()
{
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);

    gWindow = NULL;
    gRenderer = NULL;

    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

Text.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <string>

class Text
{
private:
    TTF_Font*font;
    SDL_Surface*surfaceMessage = NULL;
    SDL_Texture*Message;
    std::string text;
    int x, y;
    SDL_Color color;
    SDL_Rect src;
    SDL_Rect dst;

public:
    bool init(int X, int Y, int fontsize, char FontFile[], char message[],SDL_Renderer*renderer ,SDL_Color c)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        text = message;
        font = TTF_OpenFont(FontFile, fontsize);
        if (font != NULL)
        {
            surfaceMessage = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, message, color);

            Message = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surfaceMessage);
        }


        return Message;
    }

    void draw(SDL_Renderer*renderer)
    {
        src = { 0, 0, surfaceMessage->w, surfaceMessage->h };
        dst = { 0, 0, surfaceMessage->w, surfaceMessage->h };

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, Message, &src, &dst);
    }

};
```

Comment: Are you sure SDL is able to find the font? And please show us where you call the functions in Game.cpp

Comment: Yes SDL is able to find the font. I've added comments where I call the functions.

Comment: In your init function it looks like you aren't setting the color member to be equal to your SDL_Color c parameter.  Also try testing if surfaceMessage is null, if it is send TTF_GetError() to an output stream to figure out whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had forgotten to put the SDL_ttf.dll into my System32. 
Now the method works just fine. Although it still fails to call the method in game.ccp. :/